# Pass javascript variable into php code

Tags: php, javascript, html, variables

im trying to pass a variable from javascript into a line of PHP include code to create a more dynamic script. But so far I've not managed to achieve this.

The logic is as follows:

Looking at the below code - i want to replace the 'textfile.txt' with a javascript variable.

```
descrip2.innerHTML = "<?php include('textfile.txt'); ?>";
```

to show:

```
var thisfile = [userinput];
descrip2.innerHTML = "<?php include(thisfile); ?>";
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I know that im trying to join client side scripts with server side, but can this not be done the way im trying? Maybe with a few tweaks?
I don't want to write a hundred php scripts for something that should be so intuitive and simple... :( not if i can avoid it...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: this is not possible. you need to use AJAX

Comment: @Capt.Morgan: see my updates, maybe it help you.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question you can't do like that.

you can go with ajax request. If you use jquery you can do like this:

```
var thisfile = [userinput];
$(descrip2).load(thisfile);
```

or do ajax request by yourself..

Answer (score 0):

if your file is simple html text you can do this with [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function that return content of file:

```
descrip2.innerHTML = "<?php echo file_get_contents('textfile.txt'); ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

From your question and from what you say in the comment. i assume you have a scenario like this:

1. you have a file with some information.
2. you want populate your div with theese information.

so before going further create a well formatted file to store all the info. example

> - data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <div>
        <h2>lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>brown fox jump hover the lazy dog</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>lorem ipsum 1</h2>
        <p>brown fox jump hover the lazy dog 1</p>
    </div>
</data>
```

then use AJAX to load the content and append it to the wanted element like below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>
            var descriptor;
            function init() {
                descriptor = document.getElementById("descriptor");
                loadFromFile('data.xml');
            }

            function loadFromFile(thisfile) {
                var xmlhttp;
                if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                        var data = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('div');
                        var divs = '';

                        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                            var div = data[i];

                            divs += '<div>';
                            divs += '<h2>' + div.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].firstChild.nodeValue + '</h2>';
                            divs += '<p>' + div.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].firstChild.nodeValue + '</p>';
                            divs += '</div>';

                        }

                        descriptor.innerHTML = divs;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET", thisfile, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <div id="descriptor"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK... how would I adapt this to my jquery? currently this is the full code of this particular part:

                //Add a span to the div
  var target2 = document.getElementById("descriptor");
  var descrip2 = document.createElement("span");
  var textlocation = "txtfile.txt";
  descrip2.setAttribute("id", "d_title");
  target2.appendChild(descrip2);
                var thisfile = "textfile.txt"

Comment: can you provide more code? this is a lot fuzzy to me. are you sure you are/want use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that many times you can encode it (base64) and load that to the form to hidden input for example. Then you will be able to reuse that many times (without calling the ajax every time).

Answer (score 0):

Server side scripts will always run and render before client side script so when writing your code bear this in mind

I am using jQuery but you can use normal javascript.

```
<div id="#welcomeMessage"></div>
$('#welcomeMessage').html("<?php echo 'hello'?>");
```

if using javascript

```
document.getElementById('welcomeMessage').innerHTML = "<?php echo 'hello'?>";
```

I am pretty sure this will work too

```
document.getElementById('welcomeMessage').innerHTML = "<?php include_once('textfile.php'); ?>";
```

As long as your php file is actually outputting something.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
var thisfile = [userinput];
descrip2.innerHTML = "<?php include("+thisfile+"); ?>";
```

Though I'm not sure this is something one would need...

Comment: This will throw a runtime error in php before you get to see your page.

Comment: @slash197 Well' I just tried to respond with something - at least, "grammatically" - correct. The fact is that I was about to write about using AJAX, although it's one of those question cases where it simply is unclear what the OP actually has in mind, and what he aims to achieve...