# Setting PHP variable to JavaScript code?

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I need to change the value of a PHP variable to JavaScript code.

The value of the PHP variable has to be something out of (JavaScript) localStorage.

So it is something like this.

```
$variable = localStorage.anameofalocalstorage; //The localstorage part is js
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Only JavaScript can read `localStorage`.  So, if you want PHP to get the value, you need to send it from JavaScript; possibly via AJAX.

Comment: You'll need to get your variable to the erver through a get or post request, eventually in Ajax... no other way

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298091/php-javascript-variable-help?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836748/pass-javascript-variable-into-php-code?rq=1

Comment: @RocketHazmat Oh.. thanks, but i don't really know Ajax.. can you please give me the code for doing that ?

Comment: If you need to use a value set via javascript in php, and I think you are running the js at the browser, and not something like nodejs at the server-side, you must send the value set at the client (via js) to the server, as php is not executed on the client side. Is this ehat you want?

Comment: @EvertDeSpiegeleer: There are lots of AJAX tutorials out there, have a look around :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example code using jquery for the ajax call.

```
<?php

$variable_that_should_be_set=isset($_GET['shoudBeSet'])?$_GET['shoudBeSet']:'notSet';

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1"><?php echo $variable_that_should_be_set;?></div>
        <a href="#" id="button">Click here to Set</a>
        <script>
            $("#button").click( function () {
                $.get("?shouldBeSet=this_is_set")   
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```